# Getting syntax error (XML Config) in MySQL using Log4j2

Tags: java, mysql, xml, log4j2, log4jdbc

I am currently working on my Spring project to create simple library portal (just for education purposes). And now I am struggling with logging some actions into MySQL database using Log4j2 JDBCAppender.

To do that, I have created table in my database, using query:

```
CREATE TABLE user_logs (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `level` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `dated` TIMESTAMP NOT  NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `from` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message` varchar(500) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

   KEY `user` (`username`),
   CONSTRAINT `FK_USERNAME` FOREIGN KEY (`username`)
   REFERENCES `user` (`username`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In database I want to store information what field was modified, from which and to which value it was changed. Also logs will contain information for which user there was a change.

Then I created Log4j2 XML config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration name="ChangesLogs">
<Appenders>

    <Console name="consoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d | %level | %logger | %m" />
    </Console>

    <JDBC name="userAppenderDB" tableName="user_logs">
        <ConnectionFactory class="com.wkrzywiec.spring.library.config.LogsConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
        <Column name="level" pattern="%level"/>
        <Column name="username" pattern="%X{username}"/>
        <Column name="field" pattern="%X{field}"/>
        <Column name="from" pattern="%X{from}"/>
        <Column name="to" pattern="%X{to}"/>
        <Column name="message" pattern="%message"/>
    </JDBC>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender" />
    </Root>

    <Logger name="userLoggerDB" >
        <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender" />
        <AppenderRef ref="userAppenderDB" />
    </Logger>

</Loggers>
```

And class for JDBCAppender connection pool:

```
package com.wkrzywiec.spring.library.config;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class LogsConnectionFactory {

    private static interface Singleton {
        final LogsConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new LogsConnectionFactory();
    }

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private String datasourceURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library_db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

    private String userName = "library-spring";

    private String pass = "library-spring";

    private LogsConnectionFactory() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", userName);
        properties.setProperty("password", pass);

        GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>();
        DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
                datasourceURL, properties);

        new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, pool, null, "SELECT 1", 3, false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);

        this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
    }

    public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
    }

}
```

And finally when I am saving new user using below code in my service class:

```
@Override
public void saveReaderUser(UserDTO user) {
    com.wkrzywiec.spring.library.entity.User userEntity = convertUserDTOtoUserEntity(user);
    userDAO.saveUser(userEntity);

    ThreadContext.put("username", user.getUsername());
    ThreadContext.put("field", "ALL");
    ThreadContext.put("from", "");
    ThreadContext.put("to", user.toString());
    userLogger.info("New user");
    ThreadContext.clearAll();
}
```

I've got this error (just to make it clear, this error is only for adding logs, user is successfully saved in db):

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from,to,message) VALUES ('INFO','wojtek21','ALL','','UserDTO [username=wojtek21,' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:185)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:168)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:175)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:636)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1217)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:1009)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.commitAndClose(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:172)
    ... 59 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from,to,message) VALUES ('INFO','wojtek21','ALL','','UserDTO [username=wojtek21,' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1826)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1712)
    ... 64 more

2018-03-04 10:07:44,726 http-bio-8080-exec-7 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender userAppenderDB org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Failed to commit transaction logging event or flushing buffer.
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.commitAndClose(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:177)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2163)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2118)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2101)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1995)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1967)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:1304)
    at com.wkrzywiec.spring.library.service.LibraryUserDetailService.saveReaderUser(LibraryUserDetailService.java:86)
    at com.wkrzywiec.spring.library.controller.LoginController.processRegisterForm(LoginController.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:283)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from,to,message) VALUES ('INFO','wojtek21','ALL','','UserDTO [username=wojtek21,' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:185)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:168)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:175)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:636)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1217)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:1009)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.commitAndClose(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:172)
    ... 59 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from,to,message) VALUES ('INFO','wojtek21','ALL','','UserDTO [username=wojtek21,' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1826)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1712)
    ... 64 more
```

I've tried many things to solve it (checking typo, other configs, data types in sql table, etc), but with no success. From the error message it looks like that it is a problem with SQL insert query, but I don't know how to fix it as it is generated by Log4j2. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

I would really appreciate your support.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from` is a SQL keyword. Don't use that as a column name.

Comment: That's it! Silly me. Thanks a lot for a help!